# Transition frequency of power transistor

Tags: electrical-engineering

Why transition frequency of power transistor is typically below 30 mhz?  Detailed search on internet doesn't reveal any power transistor which can handle 5 Amp or more and has transition frequency of more than 30 mhz.  While signals transistors have frequency up to 300 ghz.

Comment: Please learn ISO standards:   mHz is not the same as MHz, for example.   Now, to your question, look up the necessary area and volume requirements for each transistor layer and I think you'll see why.